# How do i run a cronjob every 100 days

Tags: linux, cron

What would a crontab syntax look like for a command to run every 100 days?

I need to run a reboot every 100 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a [systemd timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) rather than cron since that has native support for tracking time since last (re)boot.

Create a file, for instance `reboot.timer` in `/etc/systemd/system`

```
[Unit]
Description="Run reboot after 100 days"

[Timer]
OnBootSec=100days
Unit=reboot.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To start the timer, use the command `sudo systemctl start reboot.timer`. To enable the timer on boot, run the command `sudo systemctl enable reboot.timer`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to run a reboot every 100 days

That's a very suspicious requirement.

Via Cron....

```
0 23 * * * find /var/run -mtime +99 -name reboottimestamp && touch /var/run/reboottimestamp && /sbin/reboot
```

Using 'at' (invoked from an rc.local) seems a little more approriate....

```
echo /sbin/reboot | at 11pm +100 days
```

....but what I actually do is

```
0 22 * * * test -f /var/run/reboot-required && /sbin/reboot
```